# currency converter using angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs, json

how do i select only 3-4 currency values in drop down and according to currency value the base url will be change like if i select the first value USD the Json data will come from http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=ZAR.

Comment: Before can I answer, why do you call ConvertCurrency on both lists changes; currencies and the rates ?

Answer (score 1):

To select only desired currencies in result according to a specific base use the **symbols** parameter.

For instance I want to get only USD, CHF and EUR with the ZAR base:

http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=ZAR&symbols=USD,CHF,EUR

Result

```
{  
   "base":"ZAR",
   "date":"2017-04-19",
   "rates":{  
      "CHF":0.07496,
      "USD":0.075205,
      "EUR":0.070121
   }
}
```